# TaskCanceledException on Async Task C#

Tags: c#, excel, asynchronous, task

I have a C# ConsoleApplication with the following code (snippet):

```
Task exportTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
    try
    {
        // code
        IList<OmbisLeistungsPosition> leistungsPositionen = getItems();
        string result = await ombis.Write(leistungsPositionen);
        // code
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Email.SendErrorToDeveloper(e.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
});
exportTask.Wait();


internal async Task<string> Write(IList<OmbisLeistungsPosition> leistungsPositionen)
{
    HttpClient httpRequest = GetDigestHttpRequest();
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(leistungsPositionen);
    StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpRequest.PostAsync(UrlOmbisLeistungspositionen, content);
    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
}
```

It the expected result of the PostAsync is OK, but I get the following exception on the line where the PostAsync is called:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at HGV.Personalberatung.Fakturierung770.Ombis.<Write>d__8.MoveNext() in C:\Users\EBorsoi\Documents\Git\HGV.Personalberatung.Fakturierung770.ServerApi\HGV.Personalberatung.Fakturierung770\Ombis.cs:line 229
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at HGV.Personalberatung.Fakturierung770.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<ExportToOmbis>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\EBorsoi\Documents\Git\HGV.Personalberatung.Fakturierung770.ServerApi\HGV.Personalberatung.Fakturierung770\Program.cs:line 109
```

Why do the system throw the Exception? What does it mean? How do I fix it?

Comment: Is this code just for demo purposes? If not, what do you think `Task.Run()` immediately followed by `Wait`ing on that task is gaining you?

Comment: It's a snippet. However, is there another way to await something in a ConsoleApplication?

Comment: The HttpClient can return a TaskCanceledException if the HttpClient.Timeout value is reached. Is there an Inner Exception to inspect?

Comment: ...unfortunately I can't debug the code since the REST I'm talking with does not have a test-environment and I can't send fake info.